# Load a file that's been bundled within the .jar?

Tags: java, configuration, jar, loading

I'm building a project with `ant` and during the build I'd like to bundle a number of property/config files directly into the `.jar` to make distribution simpler. I've been successful in adding these files to the `.jar`, but I'm unable to load them in my program.

What is the procedure to open/read a file that's been bundled into a `.jar` file?

Comment: can you post the java code which you are currently using to load the property file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `getResourceAsStream` method on `class`:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/myprops.properties"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load those by using the `ClassLoader` [getResourceAsStream()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) method.